# SQLalchemy with column names starting and ending with underscores

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Set `RDBMS_URI` env var to a connection string like `postgresql://username:password@host/database`, then on Python 3.9 with PostgreSQL 15 and SQLalchemy 1.14 run:

```
from os import environ

from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, Identity, Integer
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Tbl(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Tbl'
    __has_error__ = Column(Boolean)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=Identity())

engine = create_engine(environ["RDBMS_URI"])
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Checking the database:

```bash
=> \d "Tbl"
                             Table "public.Tbl"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |             Default              
--------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id     | integer |           | not null | generated by default as identity
Indexes:
    "Tbl_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

How do I force the column names with double underscore to work?

Comment: why? why does it have to have double underscores? double underscores have a special meaning in python: https://dbader.org/blog/meaning-of-underscores-in-python

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the declarative machinery explicitly excludes attributes whose names start with a double underscore from the mapping process (based on [this](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/f24c0521cee3b2c1fa224d5dbc6441b9d5f8c0bb/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py#L680) and [this](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/f24c0521cee3b2c1fa224d5dbc6441b9d5f8c0bb/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py#L697)). Consequently your `__has_error__` column is not created in the target table.

There are at least two possible workarounds. Firstly, you could give the model attribute a different name, for example:

```
_has_error = Column('__has_error__', BOOLEAN)
```

This will create the database column `__has_error__`, accessed through `Tbl._has_error`<sup>*</sup>.

If you want the model's *attribute* to be `__has_error__`, then you can achieve this by using an imperative mapping.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa   
from sqlalchemy import orm

mapper_registry = orm.registry()

tbl = sa.Table( 
    'tbl',
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    sa.Column('__has_error__', sa.Boolean),
    sa.Column(
        'id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=sa.Identity()
    ),
)


class Tbl:
    pass


mapper_registry.map_imperatively(Tbl, tbl)
mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

---

<sup>*</sup> I tried using a [synonym](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapped_attributes.html#synonyms) to map `__has_error__` to `_has_error` but it didn't seem to work. It probably gets excluded in the mapper as well, but I didn't investigate further.